# Searching for a pattern

Tags: c#, string, linq, .net-core

I need to search a list for some pattern is present or not.

```
var result=roles.Where(z=>z.Contains(x) && z.Contains(y)).ToList();

string x = "Resource:resource1:resource2";
string y = "writer";
List<string> roles=new List<string>{"Resource::reader","Resource:resource1::Deleter","Resource:resource1::writer"};
```

I need to find if any value is present in roles list like:

`Resource::writer` or `Resource:resource1::writer` or 
    `Resource:resource1:resource2::writer`
i.e Split x based on : and append y to the combination of splitted x

Comment: What is `roles`? and where is it?

Comment: @er-sho roles is of type List<string>.It is a global variable with some fixed values like:{"Resourcename::writer","Resource::writer","ASDFF:reader"}.

Comment: So how do you want to filter?

Comment: I need to find if in the list "roles" any value is there like : 1)Split x based on ':'.Then append y to each part.Please see the result which I have mentioned,you will get a clear picture

Comment: Can you give a few examples. your question is very unclear. We have to guess what you are busy with and try understand what you are trying to achieve. seems like an X Y problem.  if this is actually for roles there are much better ways to check whether a user has the role to do the task he/she is trying to access

Comment: Maybe give some reproducible code.

Comment: Tried making the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your problem is right :

You have a list which can contain anything that you names roles. Thoses roles are in format A::B or A:B::C or A:B:C::D etc...

And what you want to achieve is to find if any "path" or combination of path from x can give the role y ?

for instance : if you have roles like A::Z A::Y A:B::X A:B:C::X

you have x which is A:B:C

and you have y which is X

you want to check is you have A::X in the list

if you don't, you're gonna check A:B::X in the list,

and if you still don't, you will look for A:B:C::X

So again if I'm right, you could consider something like this :

```
        String path = "A:B:C";
        String roleNeeded = "X";
        List<String> roles = new List<string>() { "A::Z", "A::Y", "A:B::X" };

        List<String> pathStep = new List<string>();
        pathStep = path.Split(':').ToList();

        String lookupPath = String.Empty;
        String result = String.Empty;
        pathStep.ForEach( s =>
        {
            lookupPath += s;
            if (roles.Contains(lookupPath + "::" + roleNeeded))
            {
                result = lookupPath + "::" + roleNeeded;
            }
            lookupPath += ":";
        });

        if (result != String.Empty)
        {
            // result is Good_Path::Role
        }
```

This way you start spliting your path X as a list and you aggregate it in the foreach to look at each step.

Comment: Oops there's a mistake in my code. I'll fix it and edit

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Regular Expression. Try this out,

```js
string x = "Resource:resource1:resource2";
string y = "writer";
List<string> roles;
List<string> words   = new List<string> { x, y };
// We are using escape to search for multiple strings.
string       pattern = string.Join("|", words.Select(w => Regex.Escape(w)));
Regex        regex   = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// You got matched results...
List<string> matchedResults = roles.Where(regex.IsMatch).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string x = "Resource:resource1:resource2";
        string y = "writer";
        List<string> roles = new List<string>
        {
            "Resource::writer",
            "Resource:resource1:resource2::writer"
        };

        var records = x.Split(':').Select((word, index) => new { word, index });

        var result =
            from record in records 
            let words = $"{string.Join(":", records.Take(record.index + 1).Select(r => r.word))}::{y}"
            join role in roles on words equals role
            select words;
```